# Trying to make a 4100mAh, 47.4Wh battery for handheld PC

Tags: wiring, series, connecting

Stumbled across this site when searching for some info.. I'm hoping that one of you kind people will be able to help me.
I have an Aya Neo Pro handheld gaming PC, and the battery has died. The problem is that replacement batteries are not readily available.
Having pulled the machine apart, the battery is effectively three separate cells, connected together, then wrapped. The outer plastic shows '4100mAh/47.4Wh. Nominal voltage 11.55v, limited charge voltage 13.20v.

I've done some research online and found that batteries with this specification simply don't exist. However, the Oppo A15 mobile phone battery is 4100mAh 15.78Wh 3.85v and is exactly the same dimensions as the one I've removed.

So would I be able to purchase three of these and connect in series to make a 4100mAh/47.4Wh/11.55v triple-celled battery? Which is effectively exactly what's in there now anyway.

Sound feasible? Anything else I'll need to be aware of?

Answer (score 0):

That would probably work as the original pack is likely just a 3s (three packs in series). So the new pack will also need to be 3 cells in series. One thing you will need to do is get a BMS to balance out the cells and prevent overvoltage ect. Make sure you do [this proprerly](https://batteryuniversity.com/article/bu-910-how-to-repair-a-battery-pack)

Comment: Hi. Cheers for your answer. If I was to buy the three batteries, are there companies/individuals you could recommend who could you this for me? (I.e. join them in series and attach the connector cable from the old battery?)